# what should be the necessary 'routes setting' to successfully request a specific controller for ajax request in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, routes, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

**shows error 404 page not found, when send ajax request**

Here is my codeigniter's routes file.


**routes.php**

```
$route['request_handler/search_service'] = 'Request_handler/search_service';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Here is my jquery code for ajax request to a **Request_handler** controller


**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search_service').on('keyup', function(){
    var request_url = "<?php echo base_url('request_handler/search_service');?>";
    var ss = $('#search_service').val();
    if (ss != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:request_url,
        method:"POST",
        data: {search:ss},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
          $('#search_result').html(data);
        } 
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And this is my controller code
**Request_handler.php**

```
class Request_handler extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function search_service() {
    $this->load->model('Model_request_handler');
    $ss = $this->input->post('search');
    return $this->Model_request_handler->search_services($ss);
}
}
```

I need to figure out why I am getting 404-Page Not Found error on ajax requests. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you loaded your `url` helper in your controller? if not loaded in `autoload.php` and also tell all other url are working fine or not?

Comment: yes @pradeep I have already loaded in autoload.php. $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html');

Comment: ok have u removed your `index.php` from the `config.php`? and what is the location of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes I've removed it and the location for .htaccess file : ci_project_dir/application/{here is my .htaccess file resides}

Comment: ok just move your `.htaccess` file from `application folder` to `ci_project_dir` and check should be in `ci_project_dir/.htaccess`

Comment: After taking .htaccess file outside of application directory there is "Access forbidden! with error code 403".

Comment: ok make sure you have not enabled `csrf` in your `config.php` just set it to `false` like this `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`

Comment: yeah It's set as FALSE by default. I think there might be something with routes file.

Comment: I tried it either, however it isn't working.

Comment: show your .htaccess file also

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: remove this `$route['request_handler/search_service'] = 'Request_handler/search_service';
`

Comment: Hey @pradeep , after taking out .htaccess file From the application directory, I just removed first line from my routes: $route['request_handler/search_service'] =" ". It worked. Thanks man

Comment: so good if my answer helped you vote up me.

Answer (score 0):

The route is unnecessary. Remove this

```
$route['request_handler/search_service'] = 'Request_handler/search_service';
```